# Avverbio interposto, sempre possibile?

Tags: adverbs

Sono possibili e corrette formulazioni come le seguenti?

1. *Mì è molto piaciuto.*
2. *Mi sto molto divertendo.*
3. *Mi sono tanto dato da fare.*
4. *Mi sto tantissimo dando da fare.*
5. *Mi sto lentamente riprendendo.*
6. *Si è lentamente ripreso.*

Mi è capitato spesso di usarle, ma mi sta venendo il dubbio che a volte formulazioni di questo  possano essere innaturali, se non talvolta scorrette, come la quarta frase.
Voi che dite? Sul piano grammaticale è sempre legittimo costruire frasi di questo tipo?

Comment: Ho dubbi su 3 e 4.

Comment: @egreg A me suonano naturali, anche se non la forma standard. Però non ho buone referenze...

Comment: Anche a me sembra che vadano bene. È vero che 3. e 4. suonano un po' più goffi, ma è il 'tanto' invece di 'molto' che fa questo effetto, secondo me.

Answer (score 1):

Bisogna sempre distinguere tra ciò che è corretto e ciò che è "naturale" alle orecchie di un madrelingua. Nel tuo caso:

1. "Mi è molto piaciuto". Per niente naturale. Suona molto meglio "mi è piaciuto molto"
2. "Mi sto molto divertendo". Come sopra.
3. "Mi sono tanto dato da fare". Come sopra.
4. "Mi sto tantissimo dando da fare". Come sopra
5. "Mi sto lentamente riprendendo". OK
6. "Si è lentamente ripreso". OK, soprattutto se vuoi dare enfasi sull'avverbio "lentamente".

Comment: Non sono d'accordo su 1-4: non sono naturalissime ma se uno le usasse in conversazione con me probabilmente neanche lo noterei.

Comment: Direi che sia uno dei casi in cui c'è una certa variazione regionale. Personalmente, trovo impeccabili 5 e 6, mentre 1-4 mi suonano come cose che qualcuno potrebbe dire, ma che non mi suonerebbero del tutto standard: 1 come meno innaturale e poi più o meno a crescere quanto a estraneità.

Comment: Mi suonano tutte naturali e normali, un po' meno 3 e 4, ma solo perché il 'tanto' suona un po' più insolito, ma è solo una questione di una differenza di enfasi.Anche mettre il 'molto' prima mi suona come sottolineare di più il 'molto'. Ma si tratta di sfumature. Poi dipende pure dall'intonazione con cui si pronuncia la frase. Ma insomma, mi pare che vada bene tutto.